# Parsing a JSON document with a Monad to look for a specific value?

Tags: haskell, monads

I am a beginner at Haskell and I am trying to use https://hackage.haskell.org/package/json-0.9.1/docs/Text-JSON.html to parse a JSON document.

In my task, i am given a JSON document, and I would like to return the value corresponding to "index" , for example in the following case:

```
{
    "root": [
        {
            "root1": 157538
        },
        {
            "root2": [
                {
                    "leaf21": 3
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "root3": [
                {
                    "leaf31": "somestring"
                },
                {
                    "index": "foundit"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

To be specific: if presented with a JSON document and a path like "root" -> "root3" -> "index" exists, I would like to return "foundit", else I would like to return Nothing. Everything else in the document is arbitrary: root3,root2,root1,root may or may not exist etc.

Now I can do this using lots of case statements and patterns matches, but having read https://wiki.haskell.org/All_About_Monads, I am wondering if there is a better way using something similar to the Maybe Monad and the sheep-cloning example, however i am not sure how to write the bind function ...

[in my real case the value I seek is actually 19-deep in the document so I have lots of case statements]

Please could you suggest how to use Monads to do this ?

Comment: Does it have to be *Text.JSON*, or can you use other libraries? E.g. [Aeson](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson)? Or, going in the other direction, if it has to be independent of structure, couldn't you do a simple string search?

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_monads#Motivation:_Maybe

This might be helpful

Comment: Is there anything unclear about my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes those `case` statements are not necessary

Your guesses are correct - but monads are not the correct answer in this case (no pun intended<sup>1</sup>).

This is a great job for `Traversals`, `Prisms` and `Lenses` - and of course the great [aeson](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson)-library and [lens-aeson](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-aeson).

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Test where

import Control.Lens
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.Lens
import Data.Monoid ((<>))

jsonString = "{\"root\":[{\"root1\":157538}"
           <>          ",{\"root2\":[{\"leaf21\":3}]}"
           <>          ",{\"root3\":[{\"leaf31\":\"somestring\"}"
           <>                      ",{\"index\":\"foundit\"}]}]}"

val :: Maybe Value
val = decode jsonString

indexMaybe :: Maybe Value
indexMaybe = val ^? _Just . key "root"  . values
                          . key "root3" . values
                          . key "index"
```

### So what does this do?

- `decode` transforms a `ByteString` into a `Maybe Value` - `Maybe` because parsing might fail!
- then the `(^?)` operator previews a traversal - i.e. it goes through the JSON Object and follows the json path you give;

For this you have at least to know the path to "index", if this path is unknown, you'd have to invest a bit more research into lenses/prisms/traversals or do a simple tree search on the parsed object.

Here is a spoiler for those who lack time to implement a search for "index" in a json object:

> ```
> search :: Text -> Value -> Maybe Value
> search txt o@(Object o') = let f y@(Just x) _ = y
>                                f _ v = search txt v
>                             in case o ^? key txt of
>                                  Nothing -> foldl' f Nothing o'
>                                  x -> x
> search txt a@(Array a') = let f y@(Just x) _ = y
>                               f _ v = search txt v
>                            in foldl' f Nothing a'
> search _ _ = Nothing
> ```

### Alternatives

As @MarkSeeman already mentioned - a simple text search, might be much more efficient.

<sup>1</sup>: okay maybe a little bit